# Duda con lal funcion filter en Java

Tags: javascript

No estoy pudiendo resolver este ejercicio:
Necesitamos enviarle un diploma a los alumnos que están aprobados y un e-mail a los alumnos desaprobados para acordar un recuperatorio. Por lo tanto, necesitamos dos listas: una lista que almacene todos los aprobados y otra los desaprobados. Deberemos guardarlos en las variables aprobados y desaprobados respectivamente.
mi codigo:

```
let estudiantes = [
    {nombre: 'John', promedio: 8.5, aprobado: true},
    {nombre: 'Jane', promedio: 7, aprobado: true},
    {nombre: 'June', promedio: 3, aprobado: false},
]
let aprobados=estudiantes.filter(function(aprueba){
    return aprueba =>7
})
let desaprobados=estudiantes.filter(function(desaprueba){
    return desaprueba =false

})

console.log (aprobados)
```

el error que me tira es
La variable "aprobados" debe retornar 2 elementos
La variable "desaprobados" debe retornar 1 elementos

Answer (score 2):

El metodo filter lo que hace es devolver un nuevo array con los elementos que cumplan con la condición que indicaste, entonces:
Si tu array de estudiantes es:

```
let estudiantes = [
  { nombre: "Julio", promedio: 6.5, aprobado: false },
  { nombre: "John", promedio: 8.5, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "Jane", promedio: 7, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "June", promedio: 3, aprobado: false },
];
```

y haces esto:

```
let aprobados = estudiantes.filter(function (persona) {
      return persona.aprobado;
});
```

Lo que estás haciendo es decirle, deposita en aprobados el array resultante del filter, y dentro del filter la funcion recibe "persona" cada persona es el objeto completo, por lo que para aplicar la condicion que deseas cumplir debes espeficicar persona.key ej: persona.aprobado, entonces los que cumplen con eso se  agregan al array de aprobados.

Por otro lado el filter podrías acortarlo bastante de la siguiente manera.

```
let aprobados = estudiantes.filter(persona=>persona.aprobado);
```

De esta forma utilizás una arrow function donde puedes eliminar la palabra function, las llaves y el return..

Por último....

Hay muchísimas formas de hacerlo, paso un ejemplo de acuerdo al camino que habías tomado inicialmente, luego 2 ejemplos más, en este caso estoy validando si aprobado está en false o en true, en caso de no ser así la condición del booleano solo habría que agregarle ">= 7"... Y si primero en base a su puntaje se pone automáticamente el aprobado en false o true, solo debes hacer un for of por ejemplo de estudiantes, y un if adentro verificando si estudiante.promedio >= 7, entonces estudiante.aprobado = true.. En fin.. dejo los ejemplos, espero te sirvan, también agregué otra persona más, así que tendrás 2 por encima de 7 y 2 por debajo de 7 en su promedio.

```
/* Versión 1 */
let estudiantes = [
  { nombre: "Julio", promedio: 6.5, aprobado: false },
  { nombre: "John", promedio: 8.5, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "Jane", promedio: 7, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "June", promedio: 3, aprobado: false },
];
let aprobados = estudiantes.filter(function (persona) {
  return persona.aprobado;
});
let desaprobados = estudiantes.filter(function (persona) {
  return !persona.aprobado;
});

console.log(aprobados);
console.log(desaprobados);

/* Versión 2 */
let estudiantes = [
  { nombre: "Julio", promedio: 6.5, aprobado: false },
  { nombre: "John", promedio: 8.5, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "Jane", promedio: 7, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "June", promedio: 3, aprobado: false },
];

let aprobados = [];
let reprobados = [];

for (const estudiante of estudiantes) {
  estudiante.aprobado
    ? aprobados.push(estudiante)
    : reprobados.push(estudiante);
}

console.log(aprobados);
console.log(reprobados);

/* Versión 3 */
let estudiantes = [
  { nombre: "Julio", promedio: 6.5, aprobado: false },
  { nombre: "John", promedio: 8.5, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "Jane", promedio: 7, aprobado: true },
  { nombre: "June", promedio: 3, aprobado: false },
];

let aprobados = [];
let reprobados = [];

estudiantes.map((estudiante) =>
  estudiante.aprobado ? aprobados.push(estudiante) : reprobados.push(estudiante)
);

console.log(aprobados);
console.log(reprobados);
```